# Fast way to order numbers

Tags: combinations

I have five numbers:

> 1,2,3,4,5

. I want to order these numbers with all the combination possibilities:

> 12345
>
> 12354
>
> 12435
>
> 12534...

Is there an easy way to do it without listing all the combination possibilities one by one? Maybe I could make a program to do it? I want to know a fast way to calculate, and eventually get the whole list.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate the position of a particular permutation when all are listed in some given order (say, lexicographical order)? Or do you want a list of all permutations?

Comment: I want to know a fast way to calculate, and eventually get the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive algorithm for you

```
def generate_permutations(sequence):
    if lengthof(sequence)==1:
        return sequence
    else if lengthof(sequence)>1:
        for item in sequence:
            return item + generate_permuations(sequence - item)
```

Here's how it works. If the sequence is just one item long, the only permuation is itself. Else if it's longer, for each item in the sequence, place it at the beginning and permute the rest. It's easy to prove mathematically that this will produce all the sequences in lexicographic order. Here's python [code](https://gist.github.com/Bolt64/11ccaa105fce2eb1b15b) for it.

Comment: so the code lists all of the numbers?

Comment: Yeah, it pretty much does.

Comment: Do you do C++? I don't know Python.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know C++. But you could just write the function yourself based on the above pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The number 54321 is in the 120th place.

It is also in the $ (5-1) \times 4! + (4-1) \times 3! + (3-1) \times 2! + (2-1) \times 1! + (1-1) \times 0! + 1$ place.

The number 12345 is in the 1st place.

It is also in the $(1-1) \times 4! + (2-2) \times 3! + (3-3) \times 2! + (4-4) \times 1! + (5-5) \times 0! + 1$ place.

Comment: @Bananarama Depends. Are they willing to work for the result, or just want to be spoon fed answers? I've had successes teaching it this way, but the individuals were motivated.

Comment: @Bananarama Oh, this assumes that they are familiar with the rule of product, and would recognize why $4!$.

Comment: But is there a fast way to find all the numbers?

Comment: Yes, I think calvin wants you to look at that what he wrote, think about it, and deduce the answer yourself.